# Is const name: [type] a valid type def in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, compilation

I intuitively wrote a declaration like this (influenced by other languages being used a lot), and it didn't throw any error:

```
const propertyName: [TypeXYZ] = someValue;
```

Can somebody explain, why TS compiler doesn't complain and if this is a legit way to declare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to create tuples, you can have any number of types between `[]`

```
var singleItem: [number] = [1] // OK, we assign a single value tuple
var singleItem: [number] = 1; // NOT OK, not a tuple just a value
var twoItems: [number, number] = [1, 1]; // OK
```

For more details see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)